# Django ManyToManyFiled como agregar 2 objetos del mismo tipo a un modelo

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Estoy haciendo un inventario de herramientas, y quiero tener la forma de crear un carrito de herramientas donde pueda agregarle herramientas repetidas. Ejemplo(Agregar al carrito dos cortadores del mismo tipo).

Tengo Una tabla llamada **Item** esta tabla contiene todos los campos comunes de todas las herramientas (descripcion, cantidad_ existente, cantidad minima,precio unitario, etc.) y una tabla por cada tipo de herramienta (pinzas, cortadores, desarmadores, tornilleria, etc.) las tablas  para las herramientas heredan de la tabla **Item**.

Tambien tengo una tabla llamada **Carritos**  y **Empleados**. En la tabla **Carritos**  busco hacer la union de **Items** y **Empleados**. no tengo planeado generar una vista ya que quiero controlar la creacion de carritos y la asignacion de empleados desde la pagina Admin, por el momento puedo seleccionar distintas herramientas  en el carrito lo que no puedo hacer es poner mas de un mismo tipo o poner manualmente la cantidad de ese tipo de herramioenta que el carrito tiene

**models.py**

```
# =========================================================================== #
#   MODELO PARA CREAR CARRITOS
# =========================================================================== #

class Carritos(models.Model):
    no_carrito = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
    empleado = models.ForeignKey(Empleados, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    herramienta = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    # cantidad = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    f_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    f_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Carritos"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.no_carrito
```

agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesante tu pregunta. Todo lo que necesitas lo encuentras [aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). Es algo muy común encontrarse con este tipo de situaciones donde necesitas relacionar dos o mas veces una tabla con otra.

Primero quiero ponerte la situación de lo que sucede. Tu tienes un registro de el modelo o la tabla `Item`, digamos que es un 'Martillo'. Cuando tu carrito va a hacer una compra de ese martillo, el cliente probablemente solo quiere llevarse 1 producto martillo de muchos que debes tener. Ahora mismo, lo que sucede es que el cliente se está llevando todos los martillos, porque no llevas un registro de ello. Lo ideal sería que en algún lugar de tu relación pudieras establecer la cantidad, probablemente no va a ser necesario tener dos relaciones con el mismo `Item` ('Martillo'), ya que en tu base de datos vas a tener en ese registro un indice repetido.

Para solucionar tu problema hay algo que se conoce como **Tablas intermedias** (Al menos así lo conozco yo). Consiste en hacer una relación con otra tabla (La cual en realidad ya existe, solo que es algo imaginaría) y esta tabla sea la encargada de crear la relación de tus modelos. ¿Cómo funciona esto? te daré un primer ejemplo práctico:

```
class Carrito(models.Model):
   # tus campos
   items = models.ManyToMany('Item', through='ItemCarrito', related_name='carritos')
   ...

class Item(models.Moldel):
   # tus campos
   ...

class ItemCarrito(models.Model):
   carrito = models.ForeignKey(Carrito, related_name='items_carrito')
   item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='items_carrito')
   cantidad = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

No sé si sabes, pero cuando creas una relación de llave foránea o **Foreign Key** lo que haces es crear una relación de uno a muchos. Es decir, si `ItemCarrito` tiene una llave foránea con `Carrito` y con `Item` quiere decir que:

```
# * => * (Relación de muchos a muchos)

Carrito * => * ItemCarrito 
Item * => * ItemCarrito
(Entonces) Carrito * => * Item
```

De esta forma tienes solucionado lo que necesitas. Para probarlo, sería suficiente hacer esto:

```
martillo = Item.objects.create(name='martillo')
regleta = Item.objects.create(name='regleta')

carrito = Carrito()
ItemCarrito.objects.create(carrito=carrito, item=martillo, cantidad=2)
ItemCarrito.objects.create(carrito=carrito, item=regleta, cantidad=1)

carrito.items_carrito.all()
```

Comment: Muchas gracia por el  link y el ejemplo! le dare una buena lectura al enlace que me enviaste y tratare de poner en practica el ejemplo que me pusiste.
Oye como dices es algo comun tener este tipo de situaciones hay algun patron que se pueda estudiar o tiene esto un nombre ?  es dificil buscar algo cuando no sabes como se llama lo que buscas. Gracias

Comment: Digamos que esto es el principio de lo que compone una relación de muchos a muchos. En la teoría, las relaciones de muchos a muchos no son directas (como Django lo hace tan sencillo con un `models.ManyToMany`), si no a través de tablas intermedias como las que te mostré. Si quisieras estudiar algo, creo que iría por estudiar las bases de datos relacionales un poco mas a fondo